# Searching for common wave vocabulary

Tags: ocean, waves

What do you call the leading waves and activity leading before a large wave?

Comment: Can you add more context? What kind of wave? Wavefront is a terminology that could apply.

Comment: @CamiloRada it's tagged with 'ocean', so It's probably about waves in the ocean.

Comment: After more research, is the correct answer 'Capillary Waves'? If this is too vague please close it, my apologies

Comment: Why are you asking me? If you know the answer, than post it below.

Comment: I asked the original question and am unsure of this, but will post below as you suggest

Comment: I'll give it an upvote, you'll get a badge for answering your own question with an answer score of 3 or more _(that is if it's correct...)_ I'll just have to wait for @CamiloRada to check it for accuracy. :)

Comment: I don't know much about ocean waves, nor Capillary waves. Buy if you answer with a good and convincing explanation with references. I would most likely upvote it too.

Answer (score 4):

Here is what I found if useful for others -

**Oceanic Wave Clarification**

Wave position in space (x,y) and in time (t) are different concepts

Ocean waves in *time* are a vertical oscillation generated most often from surface winds creating a circulation (eddy). There are no 'leading waves' to a 'big wave' rather simply a continual progression in size.

Ocean waves in *space* are generated from the simple motion of the wind. As the depth decreases the energy density of the wave increases, increasing the wave amplitude

**Illustration** [(1)](https://www.quora.com/When-do-waves-stop-forming-in-the-ocean-Is-there-a-specific-area-in-the-ocean-where-the-water-is-calm-and-then-waves-form-in-two-separate-directions-from-that-area-of-calmness-What-elements-and-factors-contribute-to-waves-forming)

[image]

**Common Vocabulary** (if useful)

[image]

**Reference**

- (1) [Quora - >When do waves stop forming in the ocean?](https://www.quora.com/When-do-waves-stop-forming-in-the-ocean-Is-there-a-specific-area-in-the-ocean-where-the-water-is-calm-and-then-waves-form-in-two-separate-directions-from-that-area-of-calmness-What-elements-and-factors-contribute-to-waves-forming)
- (2) [Hyperphysics - Ocean Waves](http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/Waves/watwav2.html)

Comment: "There are no 'leading waves' to a 'big wave' rather simply a continual progression in size." This is a confusing statement to me. Also, there are leading waves if you are talking about [wave groups](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Group_velocity). Distinction between ocean waves in time and space is also confusing. They are not different physical process, but a different coordinate system.

Comment: @milancurcic Milan you bring good points but beyond the scope of my skillset or experience, please post an answer as you describe if possible. Curious to see and learn from!